# In jQuery how delete variables and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, variables, functional-programming

I've got a function in jQuery, eg.

```
var asd;

function dosomething(){
    for (i=0;i<=1000000;i++)
    {
    asd[i] = "(2^i)";
    }
}
```

How can i unset the variables after the function?

`delete $asd;`

With this, i can clear the variable from the memory.

But can i reach the function's destructor in jQuery and how can I unset the whole function in the function's destructor?

**THE WHY**

The function and all the global variables are in the memory after running a script.
If i run something by the console, after the dom ready - since the all variables are still in the memory - the program will run.

So I'd like to clear the variables on the function's desctructor, then reset the function, or make it to null.

Because it will flush the whole script from the memory, so my page will be faster. Imagine a bit larger data structure than a single function, like 100 functions and 800 global variables. After the shown, i don't need the variables anymore.

Comment: Note you called it `asd` not `$asd`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but aren't local variables deleted or marked for garbage collection after you exit the function?

Comment: Are you asking how to call `delete` on a function? Tried `delete window['dosomething']`?

Comment: Maybe, if i put the whole javascript into a global variable, it will execute inside the variable doesn't it? So i can clear the function by resetting the global variable which contains the function. ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set it to undefined:

```
asd = undefined;
```

**Update**
To unset a function, do:

```
myFunction = undefined;
```

You don't need the brackets. In your comment, you've misspelt `undefined`

Comment: One more question. What do you think, does it counts to the memory if i set my functions to undefined?

Comment: Nice... secret undefined ... gjobs

Answer (score 0):

Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.
Use .remove( [selector] ).

Hope this will help You.

Comment: The OP is asking about unsetting a variable, not removing an element